# I want to load product collection randomly but cache is not allowing to do so in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I can load random product collection and show on homepage while disabling cache.But when i enable cache random order disperse in magento 2. How can i achieve random order while enabling cache.

```
  $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category_id);
    if(isset($category) && $category) {
        $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_new_product', 1, 'left')
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
    } else {
        $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_new_product', 1, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
    }
    
    $collection->getSelect()
            ->order('RAND())
            ->limit($count);
            
    return $collection;
}
```